# Aggregating # of distinct dates across OneToMany relationships using Django's ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two Django models; `MonitoringPeriod` and `AssignmentPeriod`. 
Both models are defined with `start_date` and `end_date` fields. 
Business logic is such that a `MonitoringPeriod` can be covered by one or more `AssignmentPeriod` instances, which may or may not cover the entire range defined by the start and end of the `MonitoringPeriod`, and may or may not overlap. A `MonitoringPeriod` would be classed as "fully covered" if all dates between its `start_date` and `end_date` are included in the set of dates specified by its related `AssignmentPeriods` (duplicated dates only counted once).

Classes are defined as:

```
class MonitoringPeriod(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=now)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=get_future_date_default)

class AssignmentPeriod(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=now)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=get_future_date_default)
    monitoring_period = models.ForeignKey("MonitoringPeriod", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have also defined an auxiliary `DateHelper` model which is used in my current solution using raw SQL:

```
class DateHelper(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=dt.date.today)
```

The problem statement is therefore how to identify/flag `MonitoringPeriod` rows which are **not** "fully covered" by `AssignmentPeriod` instances. These cases are identifiable by the fact that the count of **unique** dates between the `start_date` and `end_date` of the `MonitoringPeriod` (ie., the `RequiredCoverage`) is greater than the count of unique dates across any related `AssignmentPeriod` instances.

In raw SQL, I can do this:

```
WITH Staging AS (
    SELECT 
          m.id
        , COUNT(DISTINCT d.date) AS UniqueDaysCovered
    FROM monitoring_monitoringperiod AS m
    JOIN monitoring_assignmentperiod AS a ON (m.id = a.monitoringperiod_id)
    JOIN monitoring_datehelper d ON 
        (d.date >= m.start_date AND d.date <= m.end_date)
        AND
        (d.date >= a.start_date AND d.date <= a.end_date)
    GROUP BY m.id
)
SELECT 
      m.id
    , CASE 
        WHEN (m.end_date - m.start_date > s.UniqueDaysCovered) THEN 'Not fully covered' 
        WHEN (m.end_date - m.start_date <= s.UniqueDaysCovered) THEN 'Fully covered'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Coverage
FROM monitoring_monitoringperiod AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Staging AS s
```

But I would like to perform the same in Django's ORM - is this possible?